Mathoverflow page using a lot of CPU
Opening the following page on my browser rises my CPU temperature to over 85ºC (and continues that way as long as the page is open): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382270/reflection-principle-vs-universes. I am using void linux, and tested this both on firefox and on chromium. My friend using windows also noticed a high amount of CPU usage when visiting that page. What could be the cause of this?

Happening to me too. Weird! I don’t have an answer, but my guess is that the mathjax on the page has an infinite loop somewhere.

Could be just the large amount of MathJax.  It all gets re-rendered on the fly on your browser.

“My friend using Windows also noticed a high amount of CPU usage when visiting that page.”  So it’s probably not a Unix & Linux problem.  Maybe report it on MathOverflow’s Meta.

Can't reproduce. Opened the page alongside other 4 tabs, one being Primevideo, noticed nothing out of the ordinary. Firefox in Deepin Linux.

@DavidG. Wouldn't that be just a one time thing? The high CPU temperature continues when I keep the page on without doing anything.

I’m voting to close this question because it’s probably not a Unix & Linux problem.   Should be reported on MathOverflow’s Meta.
